# DotNetCLI@2 pack seems to be ignoring configuration inputs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-cli

The below YAML snippet does not seem to work as expected.

I configured it in a pipeline that runs using the windows-latest image and it attempts to restore all of the projects that are in the repo, instead of looking just to the solution file.

Also, it seems to completely ignore the **--no-restore** flag

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Package to Staging directory
  inputs:
    command: pack
    configuration: $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION)
    projects: 'support-libs.sln'
    packDirectory: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    nugetConfigPath: 'sf-solution/nuget.config'
    arguments: '--no-restore'
    verbosityRestore: Minimal
```

The command that appears on the step logs is:

> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" pack
>   d:\a\1\s\sf-solution\SampleProject\SampleProject.csproj --output
>   d:\a\1\a /p:Configuration=Debug --verbosity Detailed

The above project is not even included in the support-libs SLN file the snippet has configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do what I wanted and to pack all the libraries inside the solution, however I had to use a custom command instead of the pack one:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Package to Staging directory
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: 'pack'
    arguments: 'support-libs.sln -c=$(BUILD_CONFIGURATION) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    verbosityRestore: Minimal
    verbosityPack: Minimal
    feedsToUse: select
    vstsFeed: personalnugetfeed
    nuGetFeedType: internal
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

I was also having authorization issues with the internal feed that was in the Nuget configuration and linking to that file, even from a custom command, had the same issues.
Explicitly stating from which feed the restore should be made worked perfectly and I was able to retrieve all the dependencies removing the need to use the **--no-restore** flag.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept your solution as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue find the answer easily. Thanks for your sharing again:)

Comment: For the sake of reference see documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops

If you look at the section on 'arguments' argument it states:
"Arguments to the selected command. For example, build configuration, output folder, runtime. The arguments depend on the command selected
Note: This input only currently accepts arguments for build, publish, run, test, custom. If you would like to add arguments for a command not listed, use custom."

So the 'arguments' argument is not implemented for the 'pack' command.

Answer (score 1):

> The above project is not even included in the support-libs SLN file the snippet has configured

Not sure why DotNetCLI task pack the project, which is not included in in the support-libs SLN. Since you did not share your project file structure and the build log in your question, I could not give you the directly reason for this issue.

But as workaround, you could specify the specific project file instead of the solution file. Besides, you can also check this task by classic editor:

[image]

It state the path to **csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack**.

For the ignoring configuration inputs problem, there is an option **Do Not build**, so, you could add this argument to your pack task instead of the argument `--no-restore`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: YourProjectPath&Name.csproj
    nobuild: true
```

Note: Add a DotNet build task before you use this pack task.

Hope this helps.